# How to Sort 2D array Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting

May be I am missing something. First It seemed too easy to me.I thought I can easily achieve it using `map{}sort{}map{}` ,but now it became complicated to me.

So, finally the problem is I have an array:

```
@array=(['b','e','d'],['s','a','f'],['g','i','h']);
```

and I want sorted array like

```
@sorted_array=(['a','f','s'],['b','d','e'],['g','h','i']);
```

I wrote

```
##sort based on columns########
my @sorted_array= map{my @sorted=sort{$a cmp $b}@$_;[@sorted]}@array;

###sort on rows####
my @sorted_array= map{$_->[0]}sort{$a->[1] cmp $b->[1]} map{[$_,"@$_"]}@array;
```

But I was not sure how to wrap it into one(for both rows and column). Can I achieve this using [Schwartzian transform.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: It would be a good idea to show us the code that you have written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use it,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array =( [qw(b e d)], [qw(s a f)], [qw(g i h)] );

my @sorted_array = 
map { $_->[0] }
sort {
  $a->[1] cmp $b->[1]
}
map {
  my $r = [ sort @$_ ];
  [$r, "@$r"];
}
@array;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@sorted_array;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'a',
        'f',
        's'
      ],
      [
        'b',
        'd',
        'e'
      ],
      [
        'g',
        'h',
        'i'
      ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is two separate sorts. First you want to sort the inner arrays individually, then you can sort the outer array by, perhaps, the first element of each of the inner ones.

```
use List::UtilsBy qw( sort_by );

my @array =( [qw(b e d)], [qw(s a f)], [qw(g i h)] );

# sort the inner ones individually
@$_ = sort @$_ for @array;

# sort the whole by the first element of each
my @sorted_array = sort_by { $_->[0] } @array;
```

Or if you'd prefer doing it all in one go and avoiding the temporary mutation:

```
my @sorted_array = sort_by { $_->[0] }
                   map { [ sort @$_ ] } @array;
```